# Реализация таймера в среде VC++ 6.0

Tags: таймер, visual-c++

Подскажите как в консольном приложении реализовать таймер и привязать его к отдельному потоку!?

Comment: Да какая разница консольное или не консольное. Есть унылое виньапи, есть нэйтив. Создайте таймер с приемлемым интервалом. Если не достаточно частоты, то реализуйте драйвер. И скрипт значения не имеет, таймерами да и вообще всем хардварным ось рулит. На чём вы опишите это, васик или асм не имеет значения.

Comment: Мы разбираем конкретный пример! и последний вопрос был Будет ли вызываться CallBack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В зависимости от целей можно использовать SetTimer или SetWaitableTimer. Пример для SetTimer:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool waiting = true;

void CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT idEvent, DWORD dwTime) {
    waiting = false;
}

int main() {
    UINT id = SetTimer(NULL, 0, 1000, (TIMERPROC) TimerProc);

    while (waiting) {
        MSG message;

        GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    KillTimer(NULL, id);

    return 0;
}
```

Еще примеры: [Using Timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644901(v=VS.85).aspx), [Using Waitable Timer Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687008(v=VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Получается что в цыкле получаем все сообщение от винды, а когда возникает событие таймера и waiting = false, затем выход из цикла!? Получается что процессор должен грузится на 100%, пока выполняется цикл!?

Comment: Нет, как мне кажется (лень смотреть в доке) GetMessage() будет ждать пока какое-либо событие не произойдет, т.е. отдаст управление ОС.

Answer (score 0):

Таймер в Винде умеет работать, вызывая callback-функцию или посылая некоторое сообщение. Проще использовать callback.

Как — написали выше: SetTimer/KillTimer.

Зачем это делать в отдельном потоке неясно, но возможно: в начале функции потока зовите SetTimer, в конце KillTimer, между ними — обработка цикла сообщений с ожиданием события завершения потока.

Не могу посоветовать, как организовать ожидание, не зная, зачем этот отдельный поток понадобился.

Comment: А если в предложенном коде заменить:

    while (waiting)
    {
        MSG message;

        GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

на:

    while 1 {}  

Будет ли вызываться CallBack?

Comment: Нет.

callback вызывается из default'овой процедуры обработки сообщений.

Comment: Т.е. сигнал от таймера в любом случае приходит через сообщение WM_TIMER. Задавая callback ты просто избавляешься от необходимости писать его обработчик.

Comment: Согласен! Спасиб!